# Filtering over pulled list from a database in Tapestry

Tags: java, hibernate, tapestry

I have structured my class like following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Tiket")
public class Tiket {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "TICKET_ID")
private int tiketID;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "TICKET_DRAW_ID")
private String tiketDrawID;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "TICKET_DATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date ticketDate;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "TICKET_DRAW_TYPE")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private TipDrawTiketa ticketDrawTicket;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "TICKET_SERIAL")
private String ticketSerial;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "TICKET_NUMBER")
private String ticketNumber;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "TICKET_STATUS_OF_A_TICKET")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private TiketStatus ticketStatus;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "TICKET_PRICE")
private int ticketPrice;

public Tiket(int tiketID, String tiketDrawID, Date tiketDatum, TipDrawTiketa tiketDrawTiketa, String tiketSerija, String tiketBroj, TiketStatus tiketStatusTiketa, int tiketCijena) {
    this.tiketID = tiketID;
    this.tiketDrawID = tiketDrawID;
    this.ticketDate = tiketDatum;
    this.ticketDrawTicket = tiketDrawTiketa;
    this.ticketSerial = tiketSerija;
    this.ticketNumber = tiketBroj;
    this.ticketStatus = tiketStatusTiketa;
    this.ticketPrice = tiketCijena;
}

    public Tiket(String tiketDrawID, Date tiketDatum, TipDrawTiketa tiketDrawTiketa, String tiketSerija, String tiketBroj, TiketStatus tiketStatusTiketa, int tiketCijena) {
    this.tiketDrawID = tiketDrawID;
    this.ticketDate = tiketDatum;
    this.ticketDrawTicket = tiketDrawTiketa;
    this.ticketSerial = tiketSerija;
    this.ticketNumber = tiketBroj;
    this.ticketStatus = tiketStatusTiketa;
    this.ticketPrice = tiketCijena;
}


public Tiket() {
}

/**
 * @return the tiketID
 */
public int getTiketID() {
    return tiketID;
}

/**
 * @param tiketID the tiketID to set
 */
public void setTiketID(int tiketID) {
    this.tiketID = tiketID;
}

/**
 * @return the tiketDrawID
 */
public String getTiketDrawID() {
    return tiketDrawID;
}

/**
 * @param tiketDrawID the tiketDrawID to set
 */
public void setTiketDrawID(String tiketDrawID) {
    this.tiketDrawID = tiketDrawID;
}

/**
 * @return the ticketDate
 */
public Date getTicketDate() {
    return ticketDate;
}

/**
 * @param ticketDate the ticketDate to set
 */
public void setTicketDate(Date ticketDate) {
    this.ticketDate = ticketDate;
}

/**
 * @return the ticketDrawTicket
 */
public TipDrawTiketa getTicketDrawTicket() {
    return ticketDrawTicket;
}

/**
 * @param ticketDrawTicket the ticketDrawTicket to set
 */
public void setTicketDrawTicket(TipDrawTiketa ticketDrawTicket) {
    this.ticketDrawTicket = ticketDrawTicket;
}

/**
 * @return the ticketSerial
 */
public String getTicketSerial() {
    return ticketSerial;
}

/**
 * @param ticketSerial the ticketSerial to set
 */
public void setTicketSerial(String ticketSerial) {
    this.ticketSerial = ticketSerial;
}

/**
 * @return the ticketNumber
 */
public String getTicketNumber() {
    return ticketNumber;
}

/**
 * @param ticketNumber the ticketNumber to set
 */
public void setTicketNumber(String ticketNumber) {
    this.ticketNumber = ticketNumber;
}

/**
 * @return the ticketStatus
 */
public TiketStatus getTicketStatus() {
    return ticketStatus;
}

/**
 * @param ticketStatus the ticketStatus to set
 */
public void setTicketStatus(TiketStatus ticketStatus) {
    this.ticketStatus = ticketStatus;
}

/**
 * @return the ticketPrice
 */
public int getTicketPrice() {
    return ticketPrice;
}

/**
 * @param ticketPrice the ticketPrice to set
 */
public void setTicketPrice(int ticketPrice) {
    this.ticketPrice = ticketPrice;
}
```

Now I would like to make a listing, and not only listing of this class but also search functionality over it. I have tried using [Stitch component Observe](http://t5stitch-lazan.rhcloud.com/observedemo) like following in java file:

```
public class ListTiket {

// parametri klase
@Inject
private BiznisLogika biznisLogika;

@Property
private List<Tiket> listaTiketa;

@InjectComponent
private Zone zonaZaTikete;

void setupRender() {
    listaTiketa = getTikete();
}


/**
 * This event is fired by the observe mixin
 */
Block onFilter(String ticketSerial, String ticketNumber) {
    //Date parsedDatum = parseDate(datumZaPromjenu);
    List<Tiket> filtered = new ArrayList<Tiket>();
    for (Tiket tiketaa : getTikete()) {
        //boolean include = datumZaPromjenu == null || phone.name.toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase());
        boolean include = ticketSerial == null || ticketSerial.equals(tiketaa.getTicketSerial());
                //tiketaa.getTicketSerial().toLowerCase().contains(ticketSerial.toLowerCase());

        include &= ticketNumber == null || ticketNumber.equals(tiketaa.getTicketNumber());
        if (include) {
            filtered.add(tiketaa);
        }
    }
    listaTiketa = filtered;
    return zonaZaTikete.getBody();
}
/*

    @CommitAfter
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")*/
    public List<Tiket> getTikete() {
        return biznisLogika.izlistajSveTikete();
    }
}
```

and in tml file:

```
    <div class="container_12" xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd" xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter">

<t:form autofocus="literal:true">
      <div class="alert alert-info">Select some filter values to filter the list of tickets</div>



      ${message:datum} <t:textfield t:id="ticketSerial" t:mixins="stitch/observe" value="literal:" clientEvent="keyup" event="filter"
                         zone="zonaZaTikete" context="literal:ticketSerial" fields="['ticketSerial','ticketNumber']" /><br />

      <t:any element="select" t:id="ticketNumber" t:mixins="stitch/observe" clientEvent="change" event="filter"
                    zone="zonaZaTikete" context="literal:ticketNumber" fields="['ticketSerial','ticketNumber']">
         <option value="">All</option>
         <option value="TICKET1">TICKET1</option>
         <option value="TICKET2">TICKET2</option>
         <option value="TICKET3">TICKET3</option>
      </t:any>
   </t:form>

  <t:zone t:id="zonaZaTikete">
      <t:grid source="listaTiketa" >
            <p:empty>
              <p>Nothing to display.</p>
            </p:empty>
        </t:grid>

   </t:zone>
</div>
```

However it returns only full list. Can somebody help me how can I do filtering over pulled list from a database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it solves the problem in your particular use case, but have a look at [Tapestry Functional Flows](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/func/package-summary.html). Among the other things it allows collection filtering.